# Extending JPanel to draw Image. But on the same Panel added to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

**UPDATE** : As Dmich has noted, because I am doing my drawing outside of my panel class, this is leading to recursive calls to the initialization of my MyPanel and Animation class. So how can I still accomplish drawing on MyPanel, in Animation class, but without this problem.

I am having a very specific problem with my code and I don't know how to describe what is happening, but I will try my best. I tried searching stackOverFLow, but the problem is I dont even know **what** to search.

Here I go:

In an effort to organize this as best as possible, I will first write all the classes I am dealing with.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
private Animation anim = new Animation();
}
public class Animation extends ??? implements KeyListener{}
```

So I have a class called MyPanel which extends JPanel. I haved added this class to my JFrame using
    `add(new MyPanel())`
I am using a Thread in MyPanel which calls
 `@Overrid public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`
 paintComponent calls a method in Animation which is where I draw an image to the screen `g2d.drawImage(image, int, int, ImageObserver)`. The problem is to use this method I need an ImageObserver, which I can get if Animation extends JPanel. But if I extend JPanel, nothing is drawn onto my JFrame because this is a new jPanel which is not added to the JFrame.

But if I extend MyPanel, (which is added to my JFrame) I get a whole bunch of errors.

Eclipse errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColors(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Under this error message, these 2 lines go on until terminated by eclipse.

```
at MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:9)
at Animation.<init>(Animation.java:9)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 2** Adding code sample as suggested:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Simulation extends JFrame {
private MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
public Simulation() {
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    add(panel);
    setResizable(false);
    pack();

    setTitle("Simulation");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centers
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Simulation ex = new Simulation();
    ex.setVisible(true);
}
}


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable { 
private Animation anim;
public MyPanel() {
    anim = new Animation();
    initPanel();
}

private void initPanel() {
    //other customizables
}

@Override
public void run() {
//Thread that calls repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    anim.step(g2D, this);
}
}


import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Animation {
private Sprite player;
private KeyBinder kB;

public Animation() {
    player = new Sprite();
  kB = new KeyBinder(player);
}

public void step(Graphics2D g2d, JPanel p) {
    player.move();
    drawSprite(g2d, p);
}

private void drawSprite(Graphics2D g2d, JPanel p) {
    g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), p);
}
}

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Sprite {
private final String PLAYER_IMAGE_FILE = "Image location";
private Image image;
private int width, height;
private int x, y, dx, dy;

public Sprite() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    loadImage();
}

private void loadImage() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(PLAYER_IMAGE_FILE);
    image = ii.getImage();

    width = image.getWidth(null);
    height = image.getHeight(null);
}

public void move() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    //assings meaning to keypressed
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    //assings meaning to keyReleased
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getW() {
    return width;
}

public int getH() {
    return height;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
}

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyBinder extends MyPanel implements KeyListener {
Sprite p;
public KeyBinder(Sprite player) {
    p = player;
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    p.keyPressed(e);
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    p.keyReleased(e);
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

By trying to trouble shoot the code I made changes to my code, mainly by trying to pass the JPanel to the Animation.step method and also making a separate class for key listening.

The new error list is mostly the same:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColors(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Then an infinite loop until termination of the following three lines:

```
at MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:10)
at KeyBinder.<init>(KeyBinder.java:6)
at Animation.<init>(Animation.java:11)
```

Comment: `because this is a new jPanel which is not added to the JFrame.` - why would you create a new JPanel? The panel with the custom painting should be created once when you create the frame. Then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). for the basics. Once you understand the basics, if you need animation, then you use a `Swing Timer`. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Swing Timers`.

Comment: When you have Animation extend Panel, a panel contains an Animation which is initialized. Since every animation is a Panel, and every Panel, when initialized, initializes a new Animation, you have recursive calls to Animation and Panel initialization.

Comment: And don't call your custom panel "Panel". There is an AWT class by the name and it is confusing. A class name should be more descriptive.

Comment: @camickr I am using  a thread to animate, so won't be using a Swing Timer. What I meant by "new JPanel" is that I am not extending the JPanel that is added to my JFrame using (add new Panel()). Thanks for the respone, and will be changing name of Panel.

Comment: @Dmich That explains why I had an infininte initilaization loop and why Eclipse terminated my program. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Thanks for describing what you think the code does. You also should post the actual code so that we can explain if it actually does something differently than you think it does. Generally, you should post a [mcve] which reproduces the error you are asking about whenever you ask a question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Tried my best to be minimal but complete, I just took out the thread and other minor details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was another case of bad inheritance lads. I fixed it by implementing KeyListener in MYPanel class and passing MyPanel as an argument to the  of Animation. It was bad practice for me to try and implement a keyListener to a JPanel but from a different class.

Answer (score 1):

> So I have a class called Panel which extends JPanel. I haved added this class to my JFrame using add(new Panel()) I am using a Thread in Panel which calls  @Overrid public void paintComponent(Graphics g)

First, Swing is NOT thread safe, you should not be updating the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Second, there should NEVER be any situation where you would call `paintComponent` directly, nor is there ever any need for it to be `public`, as nothing else should be calling it.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

> paintComponent calls a method in Animation which is where I draw an image to the screen g2d.drawImage(image, int, int, ImageObserver). The problem is to use this method I need an ImageObserver, which I can get if Animation extends JPanel.

Why not make `Animation` "paintable", providing a method which requires the caller to pass the information you need in order to do your job?

```
public class Animation {
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, ImageObserver observer) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You could also pass in other information which might be needed to the `paint` method, such as the model which is modelling the current state.

This is basically a delegation model - where you "delegate" responsibility for a specific task to another class

> What about `KeyListener`?

I hear you ask.

Well, to start with, it's probably not `Animation`'s responsibility to deal with it.  Instead that the controller should be modifying the state, in response to the event, which is eventually painted by the renderer

Also, you should be using the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, it will solve the unreliability issues associated with `KeyListener`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend making the class extend JPanel, but rather when instantiated take in a JPanel parameter:

```
public class Panel implements Runnable{
    private JPanel panel;

    public Panel(JPanel panel){
        this.panel = panel;
    }
}
```

In addition, I think it would be wise to make the Panel class you have Extend Component so that you have a seamless integration when adding it to your existing panel mentioned in the title:

```
public class Panel extends Component implements Runnable{
    private JPanel panel;

    public Panel(JPanel panel){
        this.panel = panel;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this doesn't work or you have other questions regarding this!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think there has been a misunderstanding. I do not want multiple panels, instead I want one panel where I do my image drawing. The problem I am having is that I want to do my animation is my animation class, outside of my panel class. but as @Dmich has said, this is leading to recursive calls to my panel and animation initializations. Maybe I am mistaken, because I do not understand if your solution is meant to solve this problem, please let me know.